# SSL not working after creating firewall rules in cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https, cloudflare

I have a Wordpress website and its attached to Cloudflare. Couple of days ago I added firewall rules in cloudflare to block my website in specific countries and continents and after that ssl on my website is not working. If I go to wordpress dashboard and general setting, the URL of website is changed from https to http and URL'S for all my images also changed from https to http. My website is hosted on AWS. So any suggestion how can I fix it?

I have checked it on online ssl checker and its fine there.
In my .htaccess file i replaced this line:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

with these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have purged Cloudlfare cache as well.

But still SSL not working. I have checked the settings in Cloudflare everything looks fine but I do not know what's wrong where is the exact issue and how to fix it.

In website URL opens with https but in browser SSL icon do not appear instead another icon comes and when clicked on that followed message appears:

Connection not secure
Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

Comment: If "SSL is not working" how does the "online SSL checker" say it's "fine"? (You don't really need an "online checker" to test SSL.) "i replaced this line" - that line has nothing to do with SSL; you should put it back. "with these lines:" - That's a redirect you should use only once SSL is working. Cloudflare Firewall and WordPress are two different things, changing one should not change the other? "the URL of website is changed from https to http" - you need to change that back.